# Incorrect sender name showing in chat using MessageKit

Tags: swift, struct, messagekit

I've integrated MessageKit into my project, I'm using MySQL as my db and PHP for my APIs.  I've been able to pull messages from the db and display them; but the name of the sender is replaced with the current user that's logged in. I've printed the sender name and it's correct coming over the app correct, but somehow the displayname is not showing the right one. Here is a screenshot with the code below.  I've checked the MessageKit instructions and can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.
[image]
Member.swift file

```
internal struct Message: MessageType {
    var sender: SenderType
    var senderId: String
    var messageId: String
    var member: String
    var id: String?
    var content: String
    let sentDate: Date

var messagedata: MessageKind {
      if let image = image {
        return .photo((image as? MediaItem)!)
      } else {
        return .text(content)
      }
    }
      var image: UIImage? = nil
      var downloadURL: URL? = nil

      init(messageuser: Sender, content: String) {
        sender = Sender(id: meid, displayName: AppSettings.displayName)
        self.senderId = meid
        self.messageId = uuid
        self.member = me
        id = nil
        self.content = content
        sentDate = Date()
        self.image = nil
        //self.kind = (content as? MessageKind)!
      }

      init(messageuser: Sender, image: UIImage) {
        sender = Sender(id: meid, displayName: AppSettings.displayName)
        self.senderId = meid
        self.messageId = uuid
        self.member = me
        id = nil
        self.content = ""
        sentDate = Date()
        self.image = image
      }



    }    

extension Message: Comparable {
    static func == (lhs: Message, rhs: Message) -> Bool {
            return lhs.id == rhs.id

    }

    static func < (lhs: Message, rhs: Message) -> Bool {
            return lhs.id == rhs.id

    }

 var kind: MessageKind {
    return .text(content)
  }
}
```

DirectMessageViewController

```
func loadMessages(offset: Int, limit: Int) {

    isLoading = true
    let me = user!["username"] as! String
    let meid = user!["id"] as! String
    let uuid = getmessages["uuid"] as! String
    print("tell me what the uuid is", uuid)

    let url = URL(string: "https://localhost/message.php")

    let body = "username=\(me)&uuid=\(uuid)&recipient_id=\(meid)&limit=\(limit)&offset=\(offset)"
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if error != nil {
                Helper().showAlert(title: "Server Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                return
            }

            do {
                guard let data = data else {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "Data Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    self.isLoading = false
                    return
                }
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                                       guard let parseJSON = json else {
                                           print("Error while parsing")
                                           return
                                       }
                guard let posts = parseJSON["messages"] as? [NSDictionary] else {
                                           self.isLoading = false

                    print("Error while parseJSONing")

                                           return
                                       }

                self.hhmessages = posts as! [AnyObject?]
                for i in 0 ..< self.hhmessages.count {
                    let sender = Sender(id: (self.hhmessages[i]?["sender_id"])! as! String, displayName: (self.hhmessages[i]?["sender"])! as! String)
                    let member = self.hhmessages[i]?["recipient"]
                    print("who's talking", sender as Any)
                    let text = self.hhmessages[i]?["messagetext"] as? String
                    let uuid = self.hhmessages[i]?["uuid"]
                    let sid = self.hhmessages[i]?["sender_id"]
                    let message_id = self.hhmessages[i]?["notesid"] as? String
                    let date = self.hhmessages[i]?["date"] as? Date

                    let message = Message(messageuser: sender, content: text!)

                    self.messages.append(message)

                    self.messageList = self.messages
                    self.messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
                    self.messagesCollectionView.scrollToBottom()
                }


            } catch {
                Helper().showAlert(title: "JSON Error", message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
                self.isLoading = false

                return
            }

        }
        }.resume()

    }
}


    extension DirectMessageViewController: MessagesDataSource {

      func numberOfSections(
        in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> Int {
        return messages.count
      }

      func currentSender() -> SenderType {

        return Sender(id: (sender_id as? String)!, displayName: sender.displayName)

      }
```

messageTopLabelAttributedText

```
  func messageTopLabelAttributedText(
    for message: MessageType,
    at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {

    return NSAttributedString(
      string: message.sender.displayName,
      attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)])
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for method `messageTopLabelAttributedText`?

Comment: @KishanBhatiya I added the function.  Thank you

Comment: You said " I've printed the sender name and it's correct coming over the app correct, but somehow the displayname is not showing the right one", so try to print (message.sender.displayName) and check